# Updating dependency breaks tagPrefix

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a WebForms site that works just fine in its current state.  One of its third-party dependencies released a security patch, so I updated from Nuget, and suddenly things are breaking.

On one page, there's a component tag:

```
<Creator:CoolComponent ID="CoolControl" Width="100%" Height="600" runat="server" />
```

Before the update, there was no problem there.  Now, it's erroring out:

> Unknown server tag 'Creator:CoolComponent'

The relevant line in web.config says:

```
<add tagPrefix="Creator" assembly="Creator.Foo" namespace="Creator.Foo" />
```

No strong name on the assembly, and I've verified that `Creator.Foo.CoolComponent` still exists, exactly where it should be.  As near as I can tell, *nothing should be breaking here.*  But apparently the compiler disagrees!

All the questions I can find on SO about this error seem to involve components you created yourself, and registering them with a `<%@ Register %>` tag.  This is a third-party component, and a reference that was working correctly before the update, so it doesn't seem like any of that applies.

The obvious problem for something like this would usually be that the updated version of `Creator.Foo.dll` isn't loading for whatever reason, but when that happens it generally produces a compiler warning.  No warning for that here, so I have no clue what the next course of action should be.  Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you post what the actual component is and what version was used initially and to what version it is updated?

Comment: Have you tried Fuslogvw: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unknown server tag 'Creator:CoolComponent'

If you see this error, it may be treated that the corresponding assembly/namespace is resolved, however, the CoolComponent class/component does not have the necessary toolbox attribute.

Otherwise, you likely see the error related to resolving assembly/namespace.

> this error seem to involve components you created yourself, and registering them with a <%@ Register %> tag

This difference (registering a custom tagprefix on a page vs the Web.config) is just a way to register the tagprefix for a single page (on practice - works faster) vs globally.

However, for the debugging purposes, it may be better to test within the page directive:

Open the custom Creator tagprefix and check the suggested (intellisense) tags:

```
<%@ Page ...%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Creator" Assembly="Creator.Foo" Namespace="Creator.Foo" %>
...
<html ...>
<body>
    <form ... runat="server">
    <Creator:ANYTHING_HERE_? />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you see the necessary control? Any other controls?

Then, try to create this control in code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using Creator.Foo;

public partial class YOUR_PAGE_CLASS_HERE : Page {
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CoolComponent c = new CoolComponent();
        c.ID = "CoolControl";
        Form.Controls.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Do you see this class? Is it possible to create its instance and add into a form programmatically? Is this control rendered as it should?

If you see the CoolComponent correctly, navigate to its definition (via the F12) key. Check the corresponding class attributes. Do you see something related to the ToolboxItem?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Creator.Foo {
    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    public class CoolComponent : WebControl { }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Creating it in `Page_Init` finally enabled me to track down the problem: the new version changed stuff out from under me.  The type name still existed, but it was no longer a `Control`, and so it wouldn't show up on the page.  Once I knew what to look for, finding the right type was simple.